# Ubuntu guest in vmware can't get host screen size

Tags: 14.04, vmware

I have ubuntu 14.04 in my vmplayer as guest os on host windows 7.Initially when made full screen ubuntu could automatically capture the host screen size.However after I had problem with folder sharing between host and vmware guest,I re-installed vmware config tools and then onwardsthe guest OS can no longer automatically pick up the screen size of the host.I tried setting the screen size from Menu->Display to 1600*1200 and it took that,but that is not my actual screen size.Any suggestions to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My configuration is host : windows 7 and vmware guest : ubuntu 14.04.
For long time I've seen if I update the vmplayer or some software in vmplayer that screws my display and then in full screen it can no longer capture host display.So today I just followed the instruction provided in this [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution) and fixed it without installing any additional software.I hope it helps other.

At first run :

```
$ xrandr -q

tanay@ubuntu:~$ xrandr -q Screen 0: minimum 1 x 1, current 1904 x 1070, maximum 8192 x 8192 Virtual1 connected primary 1904x1070+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm    800x600       
60.0 +   60.3      2560x1600      60.0      1920x1440      60.0      1856x1392      60.0      1792x1344      60.0      1920x1200      59.9  1600x1200      60.0      1680x1050      60.0      1400x1050      60.0  1280x1024      60.0      1440x900       59.9      1280x960       60.0  1360x768       60.0      1280x800       59.8      1152x864       75.0  1280x768       59.9      1024x768       60.0      640x480        59.9  1904x1070_75.00   74.9*  Virtual2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) Virtual3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) Virtual4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) Virtual5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) Virtual6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) Virtual7 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) Virtual8 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Then you can see which output is connected,here Virtual1 is connected.
Then guess a good resolution for your screen.For me I guessed following configuration.

```
Eg:cvt <horizontal length> <vertical length> <refresh rate>

$ cvt 1900 1070 75
```

The output is

```
# 1904x1070 74.87 Hz (CVT) hsync: 83.85 kHz; pclk: 216.00 MHz Modeline "1904x1070_75.00"  216.00  1904 2040 2240 2576  1070 1073    1083 1120
-hsync +vsync
```

Then you need to copy the text after "Modelline" and paste that in following command after "newmode" like the example below

```
$ xrandr --newmode "1904x1070_75.00"  216.00  1904 2040 2240 2576  1070 1073 1083 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Then take the screen resolution details from the quote and use it in next command.For me the command is

```
$ xrandr --addmode Virtual1 1904x1070_75.00
```

The next command to set it in ubuntu for me is

```
$ xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1904x1070_75.00
```

If the last command doesn't work for you,you can go back to ubuntu display gui setting and can chose the display you have added just now.For me the option was 1904 x 1070 (16:9)

However if you are fine with this experiment and have found the desired screen resolution and to make that permanent,write all the last 3 commands starting from xrandr --newmode command in your .xprofile file using following command and then save,exit and restart your ubuntu vm and you will get your desired resolution permanently.

```
$ gedit ~/.xprofile
```